# Access value of src parameters before piping to next task

Tags: msbuild, gulp

I'm using Gulp to build my web projects using gulp-msbuild. However, I have multiple web projects that need to have different build parameters to publish to the correct folder.

Here's a portion of my gulpfile.js:

```
gulp.task('publish', function () {
    var webProjectsPaths = [
        '/Project1/Project1.csproj'
        '/Project2/Project2.csproj'
    ];

    return gulp
        .src(webProjectsPaths)
        .pipe(msbuild({
            targets: ['WebPublish'],
            toolsVersion: 14.0,
            errorOnFail: true,
            stdout: true,
            properties: {
                Configuration: 'Debug',
                WebPublishMethod: 'FileSystem',
                DeleteExistingFiles: true,
                PublishUrl: 'Publish/##csproj file name without the extension##'
            },
        }));
});
```

I want to access each path being passed to `.src` before sending it to the `msbuild` task so I can make the `PublishUrl` dynamic (see `##csproj file name without the extension##`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you move that gulp pipeline out into a function, the function can determine the path and publish url ahead of time.

```
// returns one stream that builds one project
function buildWebProject(projectName) {
  var path = '/' + projectName + '/' + projectName + '.csproj';
  var publishUrl = 'Publish/' + projectName;

  return gulp.src(path)
    .pipe(msbuild({
      targets: ['WebPublish'],
      toolsVersion: 14.0,
      errorOnFail: true,
      stdout: true,
      properties: {
        Configuration: 'Debug',
        WebPublishMethod: 'FileSystem',
        DeleteExistingFiles: true,
        PublishUrl: publishUrl
      }
    }));
}
```

Then in your "publish" gulp task, use that function to make a stream for each project, combine the streams into a single stream using a module like [merge-stream](https://www.npmjs.com/package/merge-stream) and return the merged stream.

```
var mergeStream = require('merge-stream');

gulp.task('publish', function () {
  var webProjects = [
    'Project1',
    'Project2'
  ];

  var streams = webProjects.map(buildWebProject);

  return mergeStream(streams);
}
```